# Anyone gotten the switch '-segment_times' working with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

While searching through U&L I noticed a fair amount of questions asking how to script the generation of `ffmpeg` command lines like these:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:10:00 -c copy 01.mp4
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:10:00 -t 00:10:00 -c copy 02.mp4
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:20:00 -t 00:10:00 -c copy 03.mp4
```

In researching solutions for this I stumbled across this ticket in the `ffmpeg` issue tracker, titled: [Split an input video into multiple output video chunks](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1504).

This ticket highlights a patch that would allow you to finally be able to provide a list of time points to cut a video into smaller sections with a single command line like this:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.avi -f segment -segment_times 10,20,40,50,90,120,180 \
      -vcodec copy output02%d.avi
```

The patch appears to have been released in this revision of the code repository:

```
commit 2058b52cf8a4eea9bf046f72b98e89fe9b36d3e3
Author: Stefano Sabatini <stefasab@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Jan 28 22:36:38 2012 +0100

    lavf/segment: add -segment_times option

    Address trac ticket #1504.
```

I downloaded this statically built version of `ffmpeg`, [ffmpeg.static.64bit.2013-10-05.tar.gz](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/64bit/ffmpeg.static.64bit.2013-10-05.tar.gz) from the [ffmpeg site](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/64bit/), but it apparently didn't include that switch.

```
$ ./ffmpeg --help |& grep segment
$
```

Has anyone been able to get this new switch working?

Comment: Not for `ffmpeg version 0.8.16-6:0.8.16-1 built on Sep 16 2014 23:10:48 with gcc 4.7.2` obtained from `http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy/main ffmpeg amd64 6:0.8.16-1`. It fails with `Unrecognized option 'segment_times'`.

Comment: I found [this](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment). Is it what you're describing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it because the missing [`-map` option](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options), which designates the input streams as a source for the output file. I'm using ffmpeg 2.6.1 and is able to split the video with `-segment_times`:

```
ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -segment_times 10,20,30,40 -c copy -map 0 -f segment  %03d.mp4
```

If you need more elaborate splitting, you can use OpenCV to read the original video and write desired frame to the new split. Check these out: ["Creating a video with OpenCV"](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html) and ["Split a video to multiple chunks according to multiple starting and ending frame indices"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234930/83181)